# Laravel: How to use user defined functions after get data from db and send modified data to view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

### Brief

I have simple Inbox Controller

#### Code: InboxController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class InboxController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $array = array('messages'=>$this->user_messages());
        return view('index', $array);
    }

    public function user_messages()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $messages = Message::where('to', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        return $messages;
    }

    // Compose
    public function compose(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {

            // Sended data from html form 
            $to      = $request->to;
            $from    = Auth::user()->id;
            $subject = $request->subject;
            $message = $request->message;

            // Get info about receiver user

            $receiver_user_id = User::where('email', $to)->first()->id;
            $receiver_user_type = User::where('id', $receiver_user_id)->first()->type;  


            // Get info about sender user 
            $sender_user_type = Auth::user()->type;

            // Send message
            Message::create(
                [
                    'subject'=>$subject, 
                    'message'=>$message, 
                    'from'=>$from, 
                    'to'=>$receiver_user_id
                ]
            );
        }

        $array = array('messages'=>$this->user_messages());

        return view('compose', $array);
    }

    // Read message
    public function message(Request $request, $id=false)
    {
        $messages = Message::where('id', $id)->get();
        $subject = $messages->first()->subject;
        $message = $messages->first()->message;
        $status  = $messages->first()->status;
        $date    = $messages->first()->created_at;
        $sender_id = $messages->first()->from;
        $sender = User::where('id', $sender_id)->first()->name;
        $array = [
                    'subject' => $subject,
                    'message' => $message,
                    'date'    => $date,
                    'messages'=> $messages,
                    'sender'  => $sender,
                    'status'  => $status
                 ];
        Message::where('id', $id)->update(['status' => 1]);

        return view('message', $array);
    }
}
```

On `index()` method I will return `$array` which have all messages current user. And In view `messages` using `foreach` I'll show all user messages:

#### Code: messages.blade.php

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($messages as $message)
    <tr @if($message->status == 0) 
            class="unread"
        @elseif($message->status == 1) 
            class=""
        @endif
    >
        <td class="inbox-small-cells">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-default inline-block">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox012"/>
                <label for="checkbox012"></label>
            </div>
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-star inline-block font-16"></i>
        </td>
        <td class="view-message  dont-show">
            <a href="{{ route('message') }}/{{$message->id}}">{{$message->subject}}</a>
            @if($message->status == 0)
                <span class="label label-warning pull-right">new</span>
            @endif
        </td>
        <td class="view-message ">{{$message->message}}</td>
        <td class="view-message  text-right">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-attachment inline-block mr-15 font-16"></i>
            <span  class="time-chat-history inline-block">{{$message->created_at}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

And here everyone message have `id`. Here I create link to message using message id:

```
<a href="{{ route('message') }}/{{$message->id}}">{{$message->subject}}</a>
```

How here I can encode `id` of messages with my function for encode and show in link. When user click to message I will use my another function for `decode` and get message from db by id. In general where I can use my functions for `encode` and `decode`?

#### My encode and decode functions for id

```
public function generate_xor_key($length)
{
    $result = array_fill(0, $length, 0);

    for ($i = 0, $bit = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++, $bit++) {
            $result[$i] |= ($bit % 2) << $j;
        }
    }

    return implode('', array_map('chr', $result));
}

public function number_encode($id, $encodedLength = 7, $rawBits = 16, $key = null)
{
    $maxRawBits = $encodedLength * 3;
    if ($rawBits > $maxRawBits) {
        trigger_error('number_encode(): $rawBits must be no more than 3 times greater than $encodedLength');
        return false;
    }

    if ($key === null) {
        $key = $this->generate_xor_key($encodedLength);
    }

    $result = array_fill(0, $encodedLength, 0x30);

    for ($position = 0; $position < $rawBits; $position++) {
        $bit = (($id >> $position) & 0x01) << floor($position / $encodedLength);
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $result[$index] |= $bit;
    }

    do {
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $bit = ($position % 2) << floor($position / $encodedLength);
        $result[$index] |= $bit;
    } while (++$position < $maxRawBits);

    return implode('', array_map('chr', $result)) ^ $key;
}

public function number_decode($id, $encodedLength = 7, $rawBits = 16, $key = null)
{
    if ($key === null) {
        $key = $this->generate_xor_key($encodedLength);
    }

    $bytes = array_map(
        'ord',
        str_split(
            str_pad($id, $encodedLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) ^ $key,
            1
        )
    );

    $result = 0;

    for ($position = 0; $position < $rawBits; $position++) {
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $bit = (($bytes[$index] >> floor($position / $encodedLength)) & 0x01) << $position;
        $result |= $bit;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `encode` function from Laravel or do you have your own `encode` function?

Comment: I use my own function. You can show all all method. Using own user methods and Laravel functions @Jerodev

Comment: But how and where do you define these functions? Please add this to your question.

Comment: I added my methods @Jerodev

Comment: where you have put your function??

Comment: I don't know. Where I must that put. On controller or where?

Comment: You can make a class with static method of encode and decode Or you could put this in a helper file

Comment: For Example new Controller with UserFunctions I already have. Can I that methods put on controller and change to static methods? If it possible how I can call my methods from view and another Controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`encrypt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-encrypt) and [`decrypt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-decrypt) helpers. These helpers use [Laravel encrypter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption#using-the-encrypter).

Build a link with:

```
{{ route('message') . '/' . encrypt($id) }}
```

And then decrypt it:

```
Message::find(decrypt($id));
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has helper methods, [`encrypt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-encrypt) and [`decrypt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-decrypt) that can be used anywhere in your code. These functions [encrypt](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption) values with the unique encryption key that has been set in your config.

So in your view, you can use

```
<a href="{{ route('message') }}/{{ encrypt($message->id) }}">{{$message->subject}}</a>
```

And in your controller:

```
$message = Message::where('id', decrypt($id))->first();
```

Comment: I have my own function. How can use my function?

Comment: Please add the defenition of this function in your question. How do you create this function?

Answer (score 1):

First make a Utility class and make all your method static.

```
public class Utility{
   public static function generate_xor_key($length)
   {
      $result = array_fill(0, $length, 0);

      for ($i = 0, $bit = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
      for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++, $bit++) {
           $result[$i] |= ($bit % 2) << $j;
      }
}

return implode('', array_map('chr', $result));
}

 public static function number_encode($id, $encodedLength = 7, $rawBits = 16, $key = null)
{
$maxRawBits = $encodedLength * 3;
if ($rawBits > $maxRawBits) {
    trigger_error('number_encode(): $rawBits must be no more than 3 times greater than $encodedLength');
    return false;
}

if ($key === null) {
    $key = $this->generate_xor_key($encodedLength);
}

$result = array_fill(0, $encodedLength, 0x30);

for ($position = 0; $position < $rawBits; $position++) {
    $bit = (($id >> $position) & 0x01) << floor($position / $encodedLength);
    $index = $position % $encodedLength;
    $result[$index] |= $bit;
}

do {
    $index = $position % $encodedLength;
    $bit = ($position % 2) << floor($position / $encodedLength);
    $result[$index] |= $bit;
} while (++$position < $maxRawBits);

return implode('', array_map('chr', $result)) ^ $key;
}

public static function number_decode($id, $encodedLength = 7, $rawBits = 16, $key = null)
    {
    if ($key === null) {
        $key = $this->generate_xor_key($encodedLength);
    }

    $bytes = array_map(
    'ord',
    str_split(
        str_pad($id, $encodedLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) ^ $key,
        1
       )
   );

   $result = 0;

   for ($position = 0; $position < $rawBits; $position++) {
       $index = $position % $encodedLength;
       $bit = (($bytes[$index] >> floor($position / $encodedLength)) & 0x01) << $position;
       $result |= $bit;
   }

   return $result;
     }
   }
```

And in your view-

```
<a href="{{ route('message') }}/{{Utility::number_encode($message->id)}}">{{$message->subject}}</a>
```

And in your controller-

```
$messages = Messages::find(Utility::number_decode($encoded_id));//do your task here after decrypt
```

if you don't want a separate class rather than want helper functions, then you could follow [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1) link.

Comment: Ok wait I now will test you answer in my project

Comment: yeah , Or you could put your function implementation in a Helper file and make it autoloaded

Comment: I did create MethodsController on folder with controllers and call on view and Laravel give error `Class 'Methods' not found`. Where I must create this class? @Sohel0415

Comment: run composer dump-autoload